# Help/Question about Microphone / Phantom power and audio interface

Tags: amplifiers, recording, microphones, musical-forms, pre-amp

Just a quick short question,

I have a USB audio interface (emu0202) which plugs into my pc but of course, the interface (emu0202) isn't 'Phantom Power' capable,

So I wanted to know if it's possible to plug a separate wall powered phantom power brick into a USB audio interface

So it'll go like: MIC > Wall Powered Phantom Power Brick > USB PC Powered Audio Interface > PC

MIC > Wall Powered Phantom Power Brick (via XLR cbl) > USB PC Powered Audio Interface (via XLR cable) > PC (via USB)

Answer (score 1):

> MIC > Wall Powered Phantom Power Brick (via XLR cbl) > USB PC Powered Audio Interface (via XLR cable) > PC (via USB)

Given that the Emu 0202 seems to have an XLR input, it sounds like that should work.

The Emu 0202 is a very old interface - is it already running happily on your PC with no driver support issues? If not, it might be worth considering investing in a new USB interface or USB mixer with phantom power instead.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way. Of course, it might actually be cheaper to just buy a new interface that also has phantom power instead of buying merely a phantom power injector.

Answer (score 0):

You could. Just search 'phantom power adapter'.  I see there are some quite cheap ones available.   (Make sure you're getting one designed to provide 48v to studio microphones with full-size XLR connecters.  There are other types of 'phantom power'.)

Your Emu 0202 is now classed as end-of-life.  Modern USB-powered audio interfaces have phantom power built in. For a neater solution you might consider upgrading to something like the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2.